# Jena 3.0.1 and 3.1.0, RDF/XML to JSON-LD missing prefixes

Tags: java, jena, json-ld

We recently switched to Jena 3.1.0 from 3.0.1 and have found that there has been a change in the way Jena writes out JSON-LD to string format.

Below is what the JSON-LD looks like with Jena 3.0.1:

```
{
"@graph" : [ {
    "@id" : "data:4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f",
    "@type" : "assertion:assertion",
    "data:UUID" : "4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f"
  }, {
    "@id" : "data:UUID",
    "@type" : "owl:DatatypeProperty",
    "rdfs:label" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "UUID"
    }
  }, {
    "@id" : "urn:example.data.1.0",
    "@type" : "owl:Ontology",
    "rdfs:comment" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "This is an OWL ontology to describe data."
    },
    "rdfs:label" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "Data ontology"
    },
    "owl:versionInfo" : "1.0"
  }, {
    "@id" : "assertion:assertion",
    "@type" : "owl:Class",
    "subClassOf" : "data:entity"
  } ],
  "@context" : {
    "comment" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment",
      "@type" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#langString"
    },
    "label" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
      "@type" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#langString"
    },
    "versionInfo" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#versionInfo",
      "@type" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    },
    "UUID" : {
      "@id" : "urn:example.data#UUID",
      "@type" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    },
    "subClassOf" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "data" : "urn:example.data#",
    "rdf" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "owl" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "rdfs" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "assertion" : "urn:example.data.assertion#"
  }
}
```

Below is what the JSON-LD looks like in Jena 3.1.0:

```
{
  "@graph" : [ {
    "@id" : "data:4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f",
    "@type" : "assertion:assertion",
    "UUID" : "4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f"
  }, {
    "@id" : "data:UUID",
    "@type" : "owl:DatatypeProperty",
    "label" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "UUID"
    }
  }, {
    "@id" : "urn:example.data.1.0",
    "@type" : "owl:Ontology",
    "comment" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "This is an OWL ontology to describe data."
    },
    "label" : {
      "@language" : "en",
      "@value" : "Data ontology"
    },
    "versionInfo" : "1.0"
  }, {
    "@id" : "assertion:assertion",
    "@type" : "owl:Class",
    "subClassOf" : "data:entity"
  } ],
  "@context" : {
    "comment" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment"
    },
    "label" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
    },
    "versionInfo" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#versionInfo"
    },
    "UUID" : {
      "@id" : "urn:example.data#UUID"
    },
    "subClassOf" : {
      "@id" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "data" : "urn:example.data#",
    "rdf" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "owl" : "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "rdfs" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "assertion" : "urn:example.data.assertion#"
  }
}
```

The difference between the two is that the namespace prefixes data: and rfds: no longer appear next to the tags like UUID and label.

The JSON-LD is valid according to Jena but unfortunately we need to send the JSON-LD to a server that is expecting those prefixes to be there.

Is there anything we can do to control the output? We are not experts with Jena, please handle us with kid gloves : (

Below is the original message in XML format:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:data="urn:example.data#"
xmlns:assertion="urn:example.data.assertion#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="urn:example.data.1.0">
        <owl:versionInfo>1.0</owl:versionInfo>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Data ontology</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">This is an OWL ontology to describe data.</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Ontology>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:example.data.assertion#assertion">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="urn:example.data#entity"/>
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="urn:example.data#UUID">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">UUID</rdfs:label>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>
    <assertion:assertion rdf:about="urn:example.data#4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f">
        <data:UUID>4d1a75b0-484f-4dfa-998f-4382f34e411f</data:UUID>
    </assertion:assertion>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And below is the minimal code we are running:

```java
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("convert-xml-json-test/temp.xml");
    String inputXml = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

    // Convert the XML to RDF model
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(inputXml);
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(stringReader, null, RDFLanguages.RDFXML.getLabel());

    // Convert the model to JSON String
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    model.write(out, RDFLanguages.JSONLD.getLabel());
    outputJson = out.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

We are extremely confident that it is due to a change in Jena since our minimal test project only includes Jena as seen in the mvn dependency:tree below

```
+- org.apache.jena:jena-tdb:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.jena:jena-arq:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
|  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
|  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.jena:jena-base:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |     \- com.github.andrewoma.dexx:collection:jar:0.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.jena:jena-shaded-guava:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.6:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.5:compile
|  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
|  |  +- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:jar:0.7.0:compile
|  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
|  |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.2.6:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.2:compile
|  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.20:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.20:compile
\- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
   \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Comment: Why does the other system need those settings? it's the same RDF (for RDF 1.1) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1163. This is why the rdf:langString and xsd:string no longer appear - they are not needed for RDF 1.1. That changes the @type.  It then seems to impact the writing by 3rd party jsonld-java library.  See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1208 for work on more configurability.

Comment: Very long and complicated corporate story, but I can sum it up as bad design on the client's part. They are parsing through the JSON-LD as if it were regular JSON. We've tried to explain it to the client but they are not willing to make any changes. In the end their mistake has become our problem and we have a deadline by Wednesday. We're so desperate that we've been coding up a class that will parse the JSON-LD and re-apply the prefixes. So far it seems to work. Will post it up after we've run it through several unit tests.

Comment: Have a Jena 3.0.1 process that does "riot --pretty JSONLD" and read in the 3.1.0 output. It will write in the old-style if you pipe through that.

Comment: We're in Servicemix and we tried to use Jena OSGI 3.0.1 as mentioned in the other Stackoverflow post but we kept getting error after error. We also tried all sorts of things (wrapping jena-tdb, embedding the jars, etc...). We've exhausted pretty much all of our options and have run out of time. Parsing the JSON-LD and re-applying the prefixes seems to work so far. Thanks for looking at our problem so far. It is nice to know the developers are involved : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code we created to resolve our prefix issue. We've sent 100+ messages with no errors. The code works by first parsing the OWL ontology in the @context section and building a mapping from non-prefixed to prefixed. Then the @graph is traversed and the prefixes are applied.

```
package utils.helper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;


public class ReapplyJenaPrefixes {

    public String reapplyPrefixes(String jsonString) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper jacksonParser = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = jacksonParser.readTree(jsonString);

        Map<String, String> prefixMap = buildPrefixedTagMap(jsonNode);
        applyPrefixes(jsonNode, prefixMap);

        return jacksonParser.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    }

    public void reapplyPrefixes(JsonNode node) {
        Map<String, String> prefixMap = buildPrefixedTagMap(node);
        applyPrefixes(node, prefixMap);
    }

    private Map<String, String> buildPrefixedTagMap(JsonNode node) {
        Map<String, Boolean> filteredWords = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        filteredWords.put("subClassOf", true);

        JsonNode contextNode = node.get("@context");
        List<Entry<String, String>> tagList = new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> prefixMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> prefixedTagMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = contextNode.fields();

        JsonNode currentNode;
        String currentNodeName;
        EntryImpl<String, String> tagEntry;
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonNode> e = iterator.next();
            currentNode = e.getValue();
            currentNodeName = e.getKey();
            if(currentNode.isTextual()) {
                prefixMap.put(currentNode.textValue(), currentNodeName);

            } else if(!filteredWords.containsKey(currentNodeName)) {
                tagEntry = new EntryImpl<String, String>(currentNodeName, currentNode.get("@id").asText());
                tagList.add(tagEntry);
            }
        }

        String tagName;
        String namespace;
        String prefix;
        for(Entry<String, String> e : tagList) {
            tagName = e.getKey();
            namespace = e.getValue();

            // strip the tagName
            namespace = namespace.substring(0, namespace.length() - tagName.length());

            // lookup the prefix
            prefix = prefixMap.get(namespace);

            prefixedTagMap.put(tagName, prefix+":"+tagName);
        }

        return prefixedTagMap;
    }

    private void applyPrefixes(JsonNode node, Map<String, String> prefixMap) {
        JsonNode contextNode = node.get("@graph");

        ObjectNode currentNode = null;
        String prefixedTag = null;
        String fieldName = null;

        JsonNode topLevelFieldNode = null;
        Iterator<String> topLevelFieldNameIterator = null;
        List<String> topLevelFieldNameList;

        JsonNode subLevelFieldNode = null;
        Iterator<String> subLevelFieldNameIterator = null;
        List<String> subLevelFieldNameList;

        Iterator<JsonNode> arrayIterator = contextNode.elements();
        while(arrayIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentNode = (ObjectNode)arrayIterator.next();

            // Can't modify an iterator while iterating so store the field names in a list first
            topLevelFieldNameIterator = currentNode.fieldNames();
            topLevelFieldNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(topLevelFieldNameIterator.hasNext()) {
                fieldName = topLevelFieldNameIterator.next();
                if(fieldName.charAt(0) != '@') {
                    topLevelFieldNameList.add(fieldName);
                }
            }

            for(String topLevelFieldName : topLevelFieldNameList) {

                topLevelFieldNode = currentNode.get(topLevelFieldName);

                prefixedTag = prefixMap.get(topLevelFieldName);
                if(prefixedTag != null

                        // Data tags don't seem to have prefixes on them
                        && (topLevelFieldNode.isTextual()
                        && !topLevelFieldNode.textValue().startsWith("data:"))) {
                    currentNode.remove(topLevelFieldName);
                    currentNode.set(prefixedTag, topLevelFieldNode);
                }

                if(topLevelFieldNode.isObject()) {
                    // Can't modify an iterator while iterating so store the field names in a list first
                    subLevelFieldNameIterator = topLevelFieldNode.fieldNames();
                    subLevelFieldNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(subLevelFieldNameIterator.hasNext()) {
                        fieldName = subLevelFieldNameIterator.next();
                        if(fieldName.charAt(0) != '@') {
                            subLevelFieldNameList.add(fieldName);
                        }
                    }

                    for(String subLevelFieldName : subLevelFieldNameList) {
                        subLevelFieldNode = topLevelFieldNode.get(subLevelFieldName);

                        prefixedTag = prefixMap.get(topLevelFieldName);
                        if(prefixedTag != null) {
                            ((ObjectNode)topLevelFieldNode).remove(subLevelFieldName);
                            ((ObjectNode)topLevelFieldNode).set(prefixedTag, subLevelFieldNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class EntryImpl<K, V> implements Entry<K, V> {

        private K k;
        private V v;

        public EntryImpl(K k, V v) {
            this.k = k;
            this.v = v;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return k;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            V oldV = v;
            v = value;
            return oldV;
        }

    }
}
```